# error: '.class' expected return int menor;

Tags: java

Error:
 **Programa.java:16: error: '.class' expected
      return int menor;**

¿Qué sucede?

```
public class Programa {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x = 23, y = 45;
      int menor=esMenor(x, y);
      if( menor == x) {
         System.out.println("x es menor");
      }
   }

   public static void esMenor(int a, int b) {
      if (a < b) {
         int menor = a;
      } else if (a >= b) {
         int menor = b;
      }
      return int menor;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes una serie de problemas con tu método `esMenor`:

Primero quieres que te devuelva un `int` por lo mismo al declarar tu método, no debes de hacerlo `void` (*La palabra void indica que el método en cuestión no retorna ningún valor*) si no `int` es decir:

```
  public static int esMenor(int a, int b) {
       code;
       return 0;
  }
```

Así se puede obtener un `int` a partir de la llamada del método en el `main`

---

Por otra parte tienes un error en la declaración de la variable `menor` dentro del método `esMenor()`

```
public static void esMenor(int a, int b) {
      if (a < b) {
         int menor = a; //se declara toma el valor de a
      } else if (a >= b) {
         int menor = b; // se declara y toma el valor de b
      }
      return int menor; // se declara y toma un valor vacío
}
```

Es decir cada vez que vas a retornar el `menor` va a devolver el valor vacío ya que al volver a declarar la variable, se crea y no toma ningún valor.

---

Lo correcto sería

```
public static int esMenor(int a, int b) {
      int menor = 0; // se declara al principio con valor 0
      if (a < b) {
          menor = a; // menor toma el valor de a si se cumple la condición
      } else if (a >= b) {
          menor = b; // menor toma el valor de b si se cumple la condición
      }
      return  menor; // devuelve el valor, si es que no toma a o b, devuelve 0
}
```

Lo ideal es declarar la variable al principio, con valor 0 ya que en el caso de no cumplir las condiciones declaradas a continuación, al momento de retornar no dará error.

Answer (score 1):

Como dijo Riaven, jamas debes poner Void si quieres devolver un valor, ya que por así decirlo todo lo que pones en un método void es como un tubo con solo 1 salida que es por donde entra todo pero no sale, en cambio cuando haces un método normal, puede salir todo lo que paso dentro y dirigirse a otro lugar, espero que te sirva para tus futuros proyectos.

Comment: Gracias Tomas por tu respuesta.